# Sale worldpay don't go back all on google analytics

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, google-analytics

I have a recurring problem on Google Analytics. Some of the sales site for which I work don't end up on Google Analytics when a customer pays with worldpay.

Here is the method that is used

1. The client prepares its inclusion on the site.
2. The client is directed to the website of worldpay using an iframe.
3. Once the payment is validated by wp, the customer arrives on the confirmation page worldpay (still in the iframe). Here an automatic redirection is done in HTML or thanks to a link to the site.
4. The client is on a new page of the website always through the iframe in which is the tracking code of google analytics.

Sometimes the information is transmitted to Google Analytics, sometimes not, and I cannot determine the reason.

I found that when the client browser blocked the coockies, the information was not sent.

Do you think the problem may lie elsewhere?

Thanks